# #200 permissions error on Facebook Graph API for doing event attending despite having rsvp_event and user_event privileges in my access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook API Graph Explorer to figure something out.

I am using a user access token with rsvp_event and user_event permissions. I try the url: /321580178346472/interested to set myself as interested in this event.

This event id is for an event that I am the admin of the page for.

Why I am I getting a #200 error for this?

[Facebook Graph API with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgEpV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GET. Change it to POST instead.